# creating a profile page, need help ( css )

Tags: php, css

I am creating a profile page, and I would like to create a followers list ( similar to twitter )

Max 18 images across , I think 24px x 24px each icon. With padding as per the image attached.

What would be the best method for reproducing this using css. That is easily propagated using php from a db.

I am looking for cleanest method. Suggestions please.[image]

Perhaps even with a preloader thrown in for good measure, as we will be dealing with 1000's of different images.

Cheers

Well this is what I had thought of.

```
<ul class="icons">
  <li><img1></li>
  <li><img2></li>
  <li><img3></li>
  <li><img4></li>
```

then in the css

```
ul.icons li {display: inline;}
```

But would need to add 2 rows, so was thinking two layers of `<ul>...</ul>`
The issue, is I would like that if 20 are displayed then we show 2 rows of 10, rather than one row of 18 and one of 2.

But thats as clean as I think It could be done, but... I didnt know if there was a programatic way of using php to repeat the `<li> ... </li>` tags based on a loop

Plus wanted to tweak in image preloader, and I have seen these, just not sure what they are called. Uses js to handle the loading.

Comment: Do you have some code you want to share with us?

Comment: Nope. Want to see if anyone can come up with some clean code. I have ideas on how I would do it repetitively, but no idea as to a cleaner more unobtrusive method

Comment: If you have ideas share them, then we will be glad to help you in finding pros and cons for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this? 
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/QKrVg/)

or to simplify it even more, you could ditch the `ul` and `li` elements and simply use images inside a div:
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/QKrVg/1/)

Comment: yes exactly like that, hence I originally asked. Thats clean and unobtrusive :) excellent, now just need to see if we can produce the loop using php, and set the count width on both rows to match.

Comment: Not sure why there is a background image in the css? that matches identically the images in the html, or is this just to demo placeholder "fill" and set it to transparent? Which I am guessing is the case.

Comment: My only concern is padding, as your images already have a border which makes it look like padding.

Comment: you can use margin to separate the images, i.e. `.icons img {margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;}

Comment: the background image is not needed, i just had it to be able to visualize it.

Comment: Thats great, can fiddle with the rest. Thanks. So if I wanted border hover on each icon, I tried adding:
.icons img:hover {
    border: 1px #000;
}

Comment: So have changed: to
.icons {
  width: 480px;
  border: 1px solid red;  
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.icons img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.icons img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

Comment: nice, i'm glad it was useful.

Comment: thanks, now to shove it in a loop, so we can propagate it via a db. Cheers Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this is a website for Q&A on specific problems? In my opinion it sounds like you want us to do your work for you...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like the following, which will give you two rows of 60px boxes:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container{
        border:1px solid red;
        position:absolute;
      }
      ul{
        list-style:none;
        width: 180px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
      }
      ul li{
        float:left;
        width: 52px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:3px;
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>six</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
```

If your images are all of the same predictable dimensions, you could skip the floating and use display:inline on the li elements.

Comment: Issue I have is when I add a a href link to the images to link back to the profiles, I have added a 1px border to image in black, it makes the images jump.
Not sure what I am doing wrong:
.iconsx {
  width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid white;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.iconsx img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.iconsx img a:link {
border: 1 px solid $fff;
}
.iconsx img:hover,
.iconsx img a:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

Comment: be sure and define a style for the :hover pseudoclass, like a:hover{border:0px solid black;} and define the link style to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single ul or ol element, give each li element a fixed with and float:left within a relatively positioned parent.  The total width will be a function of the parent element, so if you do the math and set that appropriately you'll get your two rows.

Comment: So. like li class="toprow" and li class="bottomrow" ?

Comment: no, you shouldn't need to add classes to the li elements, you should be able to achieve your goals using just CSS.